# How can we estimate number of zeros?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $a>0$ , $b>0$ and there exists a non-zero function $\phi(t)$ such that is the solution of $$y''+(a+b\cos 2t)y=0$$ and on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ has $2n$ zero. How Floquet theory can help to prove that

> $$(2n-1)^2\le a+b $$

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know how to start to solve

Comment: where does the $n$ come into play? You have one differential equation not in $n$, thus nothing can be construed about $n$. Then you want us to prove that $n$ obeys an inequality, from an utter lack of information about $n$.

Comment: $\phi(t)$ has $2n$ zero on interval

Comment: Look through your notes / textbook for theorems that deal with the zeros of solutions to this type of ODE.

Comment: Raise to 4th order ODEs:$ F( y,y',y'',y''',y'''')=0 $, or, $ 4 a y^4 -4 y^3y'' -y''^2+ y y''''+ 2 y y'^2y'' - 2 y^2y' y'''=0 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self in this way:

We can prove that

Numbers of zeros of solution of $y''+g(x)y=0$ is less than the zeros of $y''+My=0$ which $0<g(x)<M$.

then every thing is obvious.